# How can I start a video at specific timestamp in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

Here is my component and I want to automatically play it from a certain time like 00:07:12,600, not from the start.

```
import style from './Hero.module.css';
import Image from 'next/image';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Index() {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className={style.hero_container}>
      {/* <Image src="/images/hero/hero1.jpg" alt="Logo" height={400} width={700} /> */}

      <ReactPlayer
        url="/videos/Dexter.S01E03.1080p.5.1Ch.BluRay.ReEnc-DeeJayAhmed.mkv"
        playing={isPlaying}
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        controls={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use seekTo() function after initializing to play the video from a specific timestamp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `onReady` event together with the `seekTo` method.

Something like this

```
const playerRef = React.useRef();

const onReady = React.useCallback(() => {
  const timeToStart = (7 * 60) + 12.6;
  playerRef.current.seekTo(timeToStart, 'seconds');
}, [playerRef.current]);

<ReactPlayer
   ref={playerRef}
   url="/videos/Dexter.S01E03.1080p.5.1Ch.BluRay.ReEnc-DeeJayAhmed.mkv"
   playing={isPlaying}
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   controls={true}
   onReady={onReady}
/>
```

---

**Update**

Looks like `onReady` is fired after each seek event so we need some extra logic.

```
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = React.useState(true);
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = React.useState(false);
  const playerRef = React.useRef();

  const onReady = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (!isReady) {
      const timeToStart = (7 * 60) + 12.6;
      playerRef.current.seekTo(timeToStart, "seconds");
      setIsReady(true);
    }
  }, [isReady]);
```

Comment: Thank you but it sticks at the given time and does not play.

Comment: @moemous, seems that `onReady` fire after each seek event. Added an updated to handle it.

Comment: perfect! really appreciate that

Comment: What if I want to use timeStart in a different format? my timestamp looks like this: 01:22:17,396

Comment: @moemous, the `seekTo` accepts seconds, so you will have to convert your format to seconds. It also accepts a `'fraction'` type, which is a decimal between 0-1.

Comment: I couldnt find any docs about seekTo! could you please give me some useful links?

Comment: @moemous The package docs. https://github.com/CookPete/react-player find `seekTo` in that page

Answer (score 3):

You can use `seekTo` function to start the video on a specific time.

**WORKING DEMO**

[image: Edit #SO-material-onclick-edit]

```
class Player extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className='player-wrapper'>
        <ReactPlayer
          ref={p => { this.p = p }}
          url='//s3.envoy.rocks/bothrs/goud-design-sprint/goud/LhgEcS_GOUD+PROTOTYPE+SHOWCASE.mp4'
          className='react-player'
          playing
          controls
          width='100%'
          height='100%'
        />
        <button onClick={() => this.p.seekTo(0.9999999)}>Seek to end</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.p.seekTo(0.999)}>Seek to end (works in Safari)</button>
        <button onClick={() => {
    console.log(this.p.getDuration());this.p.seekTo(this.p.getDuration())}}>Seek to end (with getDuration())</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.p.seekTo(12.7)}>Seek to 12.7</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.p.seekTo(42.65)}>Seek to 42.65</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Player />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to start the video on specific time then I think `useEffect` with empty dependency would be best approach.

```
useEffect(() => {
   this.p.seekTo(12.7)
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I want it to start automatically at a specific time? not by any buttons

Comment: I think `useEffect` with empty dependency would be best approach for that. please check my update

Comment: Didnt work with use effect

Comment: @moemous how could you say it is not working. I used `useEffect` and it works fine. please check my WORKING DEMO on codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

Following the Gabrielle answer, if you are using typescript I wrote the following code.

```
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
    const playerRef = useRef<ReactPlayer>();
    const seconds = timestampToSeconds(videoStart);

    const onReady = useCallback(() => {
        if (!isReady) {
            if (playerRef.current) {
                playerRef?.current?.seekTo(seconds, 'seconds');
            }
            setIsReady(true);
        }
    }, [isReady]);

    // I put this function outside de component due to I have the following timestamp '00:06:06.720000'
    function timestampToSeconds(timestamp: string) {
    const parts = timestamp.split(':');
    const hours = parseInt(parts[0], 10) || 0;
    const minutes = parseInt(parts[1], 10) || 0;
    const seconds = parseFloat(parts[2]) || 0;

    return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
    }
```

For me it works too!