# Playing a specific time of a video in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, video, video-streaming, html5-video, react-player

Suppose you have a full video with a total time of 43 minutes.
Is there any way to kind of split it and show only a specific part of it?

for example from 05:03:00 to 08:40:30.

Actually, I used ReactPlayer and implemented it, but it is no use. I mean it works in a different way only with buttons you can go to the desired timestamps. I don't want the viewer watches the whole video at all. I couldn't find anything in ReactPlayer to kind of split the video before playing.

Here is the code:

[image: Edit determined-chatterjee-81jeid]

Comment: You could find solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70144952/how-can-i-start-a-video-at-specific-timestamp-in-react